# List inside a List using python and Database

Tags: python, json, list, document

I wish to create a document like --

```
{ 
    "name" : "John" , 
    "DOB" : "21-Jun-1999" , 
    "Sex" : "M" ,
    "Skill" : ["C","PYTHON","COBOL"],
    "Location" : { "lat":12.3 , "Long" : "14.6" }
}
```

I am using `cx_oracle` to pull data out of my database .
Here is a small part of my code --

```
cur1.execute('select name,dob,sex,skills,long,lat from employee');    
# to create the keys             
for i in range(len(cur1.description)):
        head=cur1.description[i][0]
        header = header + [head]
for row in cur1.fetchall():
        data_dict={}
        for i in range(len(row)):
                if i == 3 :
                        c={}
                        c=row[i]
                        c=c.split(',')
                        for j in range(len(c)):
                       data_dict.setdefault(header[i],[]).append(c[j])       
                else:
                         data_dict.setdefault(header[i],[]).append(row[i])
print(data_dict)
```

This is the output --

```
{
    "name" : "John" , 
    "DOB" : "21-Jun-1999" , 
    "Sex" : "M" ,
    "Skill" : ["C","PYTHON","COBOL"]
}
```

How can I convert the last two fields from my SQL ( long and lat) and create another list .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have cx_oracle installed, so this isn't tested but...

From your desired output, it looks like you want the value of your `Location` field to be a dict, not a list. Given this, and assuming index 4 and 5 of `row` will always represent your `lat` and `long` columns, respectively, you may do the following:

```
data_dict['Location'] = {'lat': row[4], 'long': row[5]}
```

Your example output shows that you want longitude to be a string and latitude to be an integer. I assume this is a typo, but if not, you can ensure these values by using `int(row[4])` and `str(row[5])` for `lat` and `long`, respectively. Also, if you prefer to use the column names for the keys to your `Location` dictionary, you may replace `lat` and `long` with `header[4]` and `header[5]`, respectively.

You will also have to change your loop to make sure that you don’t add additional fields in `data_dict` for `lat` and `long`. And make sure you do something with `data_dict` so that it doesn’t get clobbered after every loop iteration:

For Python2.7 and later:

```
records = []
for row in cur1.fetchall():
    data_dict = {header[i]: row[i] for i in range(len(row)) if i < 3}
    data_dict[header[3]] = row[3].split(',')
    data_dict[‘Location’] = {header[4]: row[4], header[5]: row[5]}        
    records.append(data_dict)
```

For Python2.6 and before:

```
records = []
for row in cur1.fetchall():
    data_dict = { 
        header[3]: row[3].split(',')
        'Location': {header[4]: row[4], header[5]: row[5]}
    }   
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if i < 3 : 
            data_dict[header[i]] = row[i]

   records.append(data_dict)
```

For what it's worth, I believe `cur1` is an iterator and that you can simply do `for row in cur1`. This will help reduce memory usage when there are many rows.

Comment: Amazing !   Thanks

Comment: @Judi, I'm glad this was helpful. If it answers your question, can you mark this answer as the accepted answer? This helps it show up for others searching for a similar issue. Cheers.